Residency requirements for getting a TX drivers licence
France has reciprocity agreements with a number of US states (including Texas) for the exchange of driver licenses. Is there anything inappropriate about moving to Texas to obtain a Texas driver licence if you then plan on moving to France? For example, if a person moved to Texas, signed a lease, stayed for 6 months, during which time they obtained a TX driver license, and then left, would they have done anything wrong?

TX Admin Code
Requirements for new residents

Edit: My attempt to provide context may have instead created confusion, so I am restating my question below but will leave the original above.
Is there anything inappropriate about moving to Texas to obtain a Texas driver licence if you plan to move again in the not too distant future? For example, if a person moved to Texas, signed a lease, stayed for 6 months, during which time they obtained a TX driver license, and then left, would they have done anything wrong?

Wouldn't it be cheaper and faster to just get a French driving license? I mean, how difficult would it be to justify moving to Texas?

@littleadv I think the OP assumes that getting a driving license in TX is much easier than in france. ASFAIK some US states have comparably weak requirements compared to european standards.

According to an ex-work colleague, it's easier to keep a TX driver's license and residency. He was going to live in an RV and be on the go around the country.

@mkennedy - and not having an income tax is a strong incentive to keep TX residency if at all possible...

In the US we have DL reciprocity between states, but if you move permanently you have to get a license in your state of residence within a few months. Are you sure France doesn't have a similar requirement?

@JonCuster TX has high property tax rates to make up for the lack of income tax (Georgism, which is what the board game of Monopoly was based on). So if somebody is retired with little income anyway, having to pay for property in TX may not be the best.

@user71659 - well, if you don't own property. Or, at least in some municipalities, if you are a veteran you don't pay property tax.

@JonCuster You don't have to own property: if you rent a home, property taxes are passed through as part of your rent. You're paying for it one way or another if you have a place to live.
